# Undefined values in Kendo-ui combobox when we change datasource

Tags: kendo-ui

When we change the data source of a kendo ui combobox all values in the drop down show undefined values.  We are doing the same thing for multi select and it is working fine.  Is there something we are missing or is it simply a bug in the control.  We tried several version and they all show the same issue.  Our data source structure may change so we must change display text and data value.

```
//Sample code we are doing when we change the data source.
var combo = $("#fabric").data("kendoComboBox");
combo.setDataSource([
  { text2: "test1", value2: "1" },
  { text2: "test2", value2: "2" }
]);
combo.setOptions({dataTextField: "text2",dataValueField: "value2"});
combo.refresh();
```

[See example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qwKNaePPWd0uhMaWnvNC)

- Click the change data source button and have a look at the values in the first combo.
- Drop down shows undefined values but when we select one in the list it shows properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all `setOptions` documentation tells us, that implementation of this method varies for each widget:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget#methods-setOptions

So basically setOptions only supports some basic changes to widget's configuration (like "min", "max" for numeric inputs) and it varies for each widget. Unfortunately there is no way of telling which properties of a widget can be modified and which don't.

In major cases like changing dataSource of a widget (or changing columns of Grid widget etc) I'd suggest to recreate the whole widget. It's the only reliable way, because there could be a lot of magic happening behind the scenes, that we're not aware of.

You need to deselect the item, to clear the value from input. Then destroy the widget, and hook again to the input with new configuration.

```
$("#get").click(function() {

    var combo = $("#fabric").data("kendoComboBox");
    combo.select(-1);
    combo.destroy();

    $("#fabric").kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "text2",
        dataValueField: "value2",
        dataSource: [
          { text2: "test1", value2: "1" },
          { text2: "test2", value2: "2" }
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: I was trying as much as possible not to destroy and recreate since we are using aurelia kendo UI bridge and destroying simply doesn't work in this case.  We ended up calling recreate() on the reference of the kendo ui bridge element.  In our controller we change kDataTextField, kDataValueField and kDataSource and then call recreate() on the control reference.  Works like a charm.